# Numerical Integration in Laplace domain

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I need to calculate two different integrals containing a Bessel function in the Laplace domain. I have tried different kinds of methods but didn't have any luck. I don’t know how to treat the Laplace variable (s) in the equations. This is really bugging me out! And I still couldn't find a way to compute this efficiently…

$$\int _0^{40}\text{BesselK}\left[0,\sqrt{\xi {}^{\wedge}2+s}\right]d\xi  \int _0^{-10\sqrt{\frac{n^2 \pi ^2}{100}+s}}\text{BesselK}\left[0,\sqrt{(-\text{Log}[\tau ])^{2}+\left(\frac{n^2 \pi ^2}{100}+s\right)}\right] \times \text{Cos}\left[n \pi  \frac{50+\left(15-\frac{\text{Log}[\tau ]}{\sqrt{\frac{n^2 \pi ^2}{100}+s}}\right)\text{Cot}[30^{\circ}]}{100}\right]\frac{1}{\tau }d\tau$$

Can anyone provide an insight?

@LeonidKovalev, these is my code to generate my results:

`eq1[s_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[BesselK[0, Sqrt[u^2 + s]], {u, 0, 40}];
eq2[s_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[BesselK[0, Sqrt[u^2 + s]], {u, 0, -10}];
eq3[s_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
   BesselK[0, Sqrt[(-Log[t])^2 + ((n^2 [Pi]^2)/100 + s)]] Cos[
     n [Pi] (50 + (15 - Log[t]/Sqrt[(n^2 [Pi]^2)/100 + s]) Cot[
           30 Degree])/100] 1/t, {t, 
    0, -10 Sqrt[(n^2 [Pi]^2)/100 + s]}];

eq4[s_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
   BesselK[0, Sqrt[(-Log[t])^2 + ((n^2 [Pi]^2)/100 + s)]] Cos[
     n [Pi] (50 + (15 - Log[t]/Sqrt[(n^2 [Pi]^2)/100 + s]) Cot[
           30 Degree])/100] 1/t, {t, 0, 
    40 Sqrt[(n^2 [Pi]^2)/100 + s]}];

PD[s_] = (1/(s^(3/2) 100 Sin[30 Degree]) (eq1[s] - eq2[s]) + 
    2/(s 100 Sin[30 Degree]) Sum[
      1/Sqrt[(n^2 [Pi]^2)/100 + s]*
       Cos[n [Pi]/2]*(eq3[s, n] - eq4[s, n]), {n, 1, 10}]);

SetOptions[NIntegrate, Method -> "ClenshawCurtisRule", 
  WorkingPrecision -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 2];

Ni = 8;
V[i_, NN_] = (-1)^(i + NN/2) !(
*UnderoverscriptBox[([Sum]), (k = Floor[
*FractionBox[(1 + i), (2)]]), (Min[i, 
*FractionBox[(NN), (2)]])]
*FractionBox[(
*SuperscriptBox[(k), (1 + 
*FractionBox[(NN), (2)])]\ (((2\ k))!)), ((((i - 
        k))!)\ 
*SuperscriptBox[(((k!))), (2)]\ ((((-i) + 
        2\ k))!)\ ((((-k) + 
*FractionBox[(NN), (2)]))!))]); (*Algoritmo de Inversão \
numérica (Stehfest(1970))*)
PD1[tD_] = (Log[2] !(
*UnderoverscriptBox[([Sum]), (i = 1), (Ni)](PD[
*FractionBox[(i\ Log[2]), (tD)]]\ V[i, Ni])))/tD;

LogLogPlot[{PD1[y], y*PD1'[y]}, {y, 0.1, 1000000}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Black}, {Dashed, Black}}, Frame -> True]`

Comment: Unlikely, if the code remains as unreadable as it is now.

Comment: That's weird... Looks fine to me. I'm trying change it...

Comment: I don't know what am i doing wrong... I tried to upload a image, but I need 10 reputations for this.

Comment: OK, you got 10 rep points now. :)

Comment: @LeonidKovalev, thanks!

Comment: Now I see the formulas, but don't quite understand your goal. If you want to use numerical integration, you should have numerical value(s) of $s$. You could insert the numerical integration command in a loop over s = k/100, k integer.

Comment: The thing is that "s" is the Laplace variable and I can't give it a value. My goal is to  calculate numerically these integrals because eventually I'll put it into a numerical inversion algorithm for time domain...

Comment: If $s$ is a symbolic variable, then you need a symbolic integration  routine. Which will probably fail to produce any output when given a complex integral of this kind. (I presume you tried this with Mathematica). You could try to expand Bessel function into a power series: this may help for the first integral, but the second looks hopeless.

Comment: I have added the Mathematica codes in my question. Unfortunatly the results do not look very good and take a very long time to compute… This is really bugging me out! And I still couldn't find a way to compute this efficiently…